# how to verify date of birth on Microsoft account on my nokia-lumia-520

Tags: lumia-520

How to verify the date of birth on Microsoft account? And how to create a new account on my Nokia Lumia 520

Answer (score 1):

The birthday saved to your Microsoft account can be seen here. https://account.live.com/SummaryPage.aspx

If you want to change the main Microsoft account on your Windows phone you'll have to do a factory reset.